# Replace parent node by child node in json

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a JSon object like this:

```
{
    "coach": {
        "Errors": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "errorMessage": "You must select a date that is in the future.",
                    "errorBOPath": "twl.date"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

and I want to remove the items but need to move the data of items to Errors, and make Error becomes array. The expected data like this:

```
{
  "coach": {
    "Errors": [
      {
        "errorMessage": "You must select a date that is in the future.",
        "errorBOPath": "twl.date" 
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

"coach" and "errors" are not fixed, "items" is fixed. eg:

```
{
  "results": {
    "items": [
      "a",
      "b"
    ]
  }
}
```

Please advice me

Comment: please show us your code what you tried. this is a fairly simple task

Comment: @PhilippSander: Tks for your the response,  I'm the newcomer in json.  current I don't have any ideas for that, Could you advise me?

Answer (score 0):

`jsonObjectVariable.coach.Errors = jsonObjectVariable.coach.Errors.items`

https://jsfiddle.net/uq6nc7bm/1/

Comment: From your comment: "coach" and "errors" are not fixed, "items" is fixed. eg:

{
  "results": {
    "items": [
      "a",
      "b"
    ]
  }
}

Comment: you will need to use Object.req() then